# Java String to date conversion error for format yyyyMMddhhmmss

Tags: java, date

I am getting error only for the specific string field ,I have given my code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String sDate1="201710164425";  
    Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").parse(sDate1);  
    System.out.println(sDate1+"\t"+date1);  
}
```

If i change String to addding 0 before 4  `sDate1="2017101604425";` it works fine, I get `Mon Oct 16 04:42:05 IST 2017`, but my input comes in this way `sDate1="201710164425";`
Help me to have a better solution for this ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide what is suppose to be this date exactly. `201710164425` -> `2017-10-16 4-4-25`? or `2017-10-16 4-42-5`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: So if you got 201710161234, how would you know if the time was supposed to be 12:03:04, 01:23:04 or 01:02:34? Haven’t you got an impossible problem? Best if you can receive a string in ISO 8601 format. It goes like `2017-10-16T04:42:05` and is widely used.

Comment: You have a data input problem, not a data parsing problem. Fix the source of that data. And educate the programmer of that source about the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to have an "hour value" without leading zero, I also see that minutes and/or seconds should be the same, so you could use a time format like `Hms`.

- H : Hour in day (0-23) or (k : Hour in day (1-24) )
- m : Minute in hour
- s : Second in minute

Compared to `HHmmss`, having a format like `Hms` would only take the least amount of digit for each field (that more complicated but it's the idea).

## Problem

That could be miss interpreted. Let say I want to send you a time like `01:21:05`, it will look like `1215` to match the pattern you need.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("Hms")
```

> 1215  -> 01:02:15

See the problem ? `01:21:05` will be come `01:02:15`.

I always suggest to use leading zero (two digit) for every field to prevent any mistake.

## Solution

1. Use leading zero

Use two digit for each of your field to prevent any problem

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss")
```

> 012105    ->  01:21:05

2. Add some separators

You can define a pattern to use separator between each field:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("H:m:s")
```

> 1:21:5    ->  01:21:05

Answer (score 4):

```
yyyyMMddhhmmss  <- format
201710164425    <- data
```

so for 4th hour you need to do `04` (hh) instead of 4. Same for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using another pattern in `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
 yyyyMMddKmmssa
```

Where

```
 K  - Hour in am/pm (0-11)
 a  - Am/pm marker
```

**Notice that you need the last 'a'**. If you want just a single 4 to indicate both 04:00 and 16:00, you need something to differentiate between them.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is not the missing AM/PM marker, but that uppercase `H` was intended, that is, hour-of-day from 0 through 23. But the OP can better tell.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right. I have upvoted AxelH answer. There are a lot of problems with OP's format.